# Extract string pattern from data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the one-column dataframe `df` as below:

| column1 |
| --- |
| 638hshsys-name123x73632 |
| ydgcg2763,sd8nameyux2ksdj |
| name2ux@SDJ sLlsakdal |

I'd like to extract a substring matching the pattern `namexxx` from this column and create a new *column2*, i.e. the word `name` and the following 3 characters, like below:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 638hshsys-name123x73632 | name123 |
| ydgcg2763,sd8nameyux2ksdj | nameyux |
| name2ux@SDJ sLlsakdal | name2ux |

Comment: @Erfan I'm a bit biased about this. I'm always watching out for the `informed` badge. If it's there, I'm *much* more forgiving :)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Series.str.extract` with a regex pattern where we match "any" character with length 3:

```
df['column2'] = df['column1'].str.extract("(name.{3})")

                     column1  column2
0    638hshsys-name123x73632  name123
1  ydgcg2763,sd8nameyux2ksdj  nameyux
2      name2ux@SDJ sLlsakdal  name2ux
```

Comment: got an error stringmethods obejct is not callable @Erfan

Comment: Not sure why that happens. Based on your example data, I cannot reproduce your error. Did you type the name correctly? It's `column` and not `colunm`

Comment: @swan212 maybe just some typo? The answer definitively works as described